# Rectangle with triangular side in css

Tags: css

Considering the dark gray section is the element sitting below, how can the golden shape in the picture be drawn with css exclusively?

[image]

This is my code so far:

```css
.Header--wrapper {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #42424C;
}

.Header--start-small {
  width: 25%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #BCB097;
  color: white;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 57px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div className="Header--wrapper">
  <div className="Header--start-small"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your html code. Have you tried something?

Comment: I added the html and css code. However I just need directions on how to create that kind of angle, I do not need help on the existing code.

Comment: @feychou If you get gray triangle that overlaps golden rectange is this OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
#container {
  height: 80px;
  width: 300px;
  background: #ebebeb;
}

#container:before {
  content: " ";
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 40px 0 40px 20px;
  border-color: #ebebeb #ebebeb #ebebeb white;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Note that you can adjust the depth of the cut out by changing the last value in the `border-width` relative to the other values

Answer (score 3):

Please refer blow code, I have update css and html.

```css
.Header--wrapper {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #BCB097;
    height: 40px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.Header--start-small {
width: 25%;
position: absolute;
background-color: #42424C;
color: white;
margin-top: -10px;
margin-left: 0px;
padding-bottom: 57px;
display: inline-block
}
.Arrow{
width: 0;
height: 0;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 20px 0 20px 10px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #42424c;
display: inline-block;
left: 25%;
position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="Header--wrapper">
  <div class="Header--start-small"></div><div class="Arrow"></div>
</div>
```